# Chrome crash every time open github on Ubuntu linux

Tags: google-chrome, github

Since github using webfront for icons, every time I open github website that tab will crash. But other websites are not crash.

I did everything I can, like disable all extensions, clean all cache, even create a new user profile, still not working.

I'm using Ubuntu linux 12.04, last stable google chrome browser, always up to date.

I searched from google and not found any one has the issue like mine.

And I found any website using [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) my chrome tab will crash if I open that website.

Comment: does it work with any other browsers?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a general purpose support forum, it's for programming questions and this is off-topic here.

Comment: @steelclaw Yes, websites are all working with Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @meagar OK, I think I should ask this question on askubuntu.com, sorry.

Comment: @harry I am experiencing the same problem on OS X. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @giant91 I have not find any solution on ubuntu. I am using OS X now and the problem is not happen any more.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem. I've been using Chromium ever since. Chromium solved all my problems. You can get it in the Software Center.